# Setup a new Server2008R2 DC

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller

I need to config a new DC 2008 R2 for a different client. Is it ok to setup within the current domain network? If I'm doing this, is it messing up anything with the current DC?

Comment: Why would you setup a server for Client B inside of Client A's network? If it is two completely separate domain environments, set it up in a lab or at the appropriate clients site.

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking...

Comment: I dont have a lab network that is why I'm asking if there is any issue? I guess need to config at the client site is better.

Comment: No lab is totally fine, but I wouldn't want a (presumed) contractor working on other clients stuff in my building.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "within the current domain network".

1. If it's just on the same LAN and there's not going to be any sort of domain relationship (same domain or same forest), then go nuts. Whatever.
2. If you think you're going to do this as a new DC in your existing domain or forest, no way. Problems yes.

Comment: As a caveat to #1, if the new DC is configured to provide DHCP it could cause issues with the existing environment.

Comment: Yup, but that applies to any piece of equipment, not just a DC. You plug the LAN port of a home router into a network and you have a rogue DHCP server, too. Not specific to his question.

Comment: From my experience, DC's in small business environments are often used for DHCP.  Given the tone/content of the message from the OP, I think it is something that could get overlooked. :)  That's all I was getting at.